# streaming rtsp server (android)

Tags: android, rtsp, rtp, libstreaming

I am making an android application for streaming local video files to other android phones.

For this purpose, I found the libstreaming library, but it is designed to stream video from the camera phone.

How can I stream local video files using this library? 
Are there any other libraries with which you can implement streaming?

I tried to use headless vlc but headless vlc does not exist in android.
I tried to use gstreamer (gst-launch) but MediaPlayer is required to sdp the file.
ffserver is not supported..

Comment: `How can I stream local video files using this library?` this is quite broad and `Are there any other libraries` is off-topic :) rather describe what you've tried so far and what you're struggling with

Comment: other libray not offtopic.

Comment: it is off-topic - `"It's seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources. This question is likely to lead to opinion-based answers."`

Comment: Other libraries are not off-topic.
We tried to use headless vlc but headless vlc does not exist in android.
We tried to use gstreamer (gst-launch) but MediaPlayer is required to sdp the file.
ffserver is not supported.